# How to select number of topics for Latent Dirichlet Allocation Topic-Model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, topic-modeling

I am new to topic modeling and I came across LDA model, but I am not sure if I am using it good. As far as I read the documentation, parameter called `n_components` is parameter that represent number of topics, am I right?
This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer


# Reading Dataset (all textual data)
df = pd.read_csv("final_dataset.csv")
df = df[df.groupby('Textelements')['MainCategoryName'].transform('nunique') == 1]
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df = df.dropna()
df = df.reset_index(drop = True)

print(df.shape) # (63197, 2)

# I am selecting 5000 rows
df = df.head(5000)

# Shuffling the dataset
for i in range(4):
    df = df.sample(frac=1)

    

features = df["Textelements"]
print(type(features)) # <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

transformerVectoriser = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,1), max_features = 5000)
vectorized_features = transformerVectoriser.fit_transform(features)
print(type(vectorized_features)) # <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>


# Build LDA Model
model = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components = 20,               # Number of topics
                                    max_iter = 10,               # Max learning iterations
                                    learning_method='online',   
                                    random_state=100,          # Random state
                                    batch_size=128,            # n docs in each learning iter
                                    evaluate_every = -1,       # compute perplexity every n iters, default: Don't
                                    n_jobs = -1,               # Use all available CPUs
                                )


model = model.fit_transform(vectorized_features)
```

My question is how to calculate accuracy?
I do not know if I have 5,10 or 500 topics (n_components parameter in model, right?), so I want to see accuracy for specific number of topics in order to know what number to set for n_components

Comment: LDA is an unsupervised algorithm, so you really can not calculate accuracy here.

Comment: I have read about the something that is called "likelihood"

Comment: I guess you are referring to **Perplexity**: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html#sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.perplexity